# SAM CLI deploy lambdas in VPC and serverless api gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to create 2 lambda functions in private subnets of VPC, the lambdas will be called from an API Gateway.

The api gateway will have several paths to the lambdas.

I've created 2 VPC endpoints, one for the lambdas to call the Secrets Manager where the user and password access to the RDS Aurora are stored and a VPC endpoint for api gateway, so it can call the lambda functions.

The issue I'm facing is that I'm getting the error message:
`{ "message": "Internal server error" }`
When trying to request my API Gateway.

My lambda function doesn't even seem to be requested, when I request it manually with test button in AWS Console it works and generates logs, but calling from the API Gateway using postman in my machine, just returns the error, the lambda function doesn't generate logs and the gateway logs doesn't tell me much. Example of log from the gateway:

```
{
    "requestId": "id",
    "ip": "ipv4",
    "caller": "-",
    "user": "-",
    "requestTime": "31/Mar/2023:15:47:35 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "resourcePath": "/{database_name}/{table_name}",
    "status": "500",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "36"
}
```

This is my current main.yaml file to deploy all the services using SAM CLI:

```
Resources:
  DcpBackendReaderRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: DcpBackendReaderRole
      Tags:
        - Key: "env"
          Value: "3"
        - Key: "serviceGroup"
          Value: "2"
        - Key: "owner"
          Value: "1"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: SecretsManagerReadAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:secrets/manager/key/for/user/and/pss-*'
        - PolicyName: KMSDecryptAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kms:Decrypt
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:kms:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:key/key-id'

  DcpBackendWriterRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: DcpBackendWriterRole
      Tags:
        - Key: "env"
          Value: "3"
        - Key: "serviceGroup"
          Value: "2"
        - Key: "owner"
          Value: "1"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: SecretsManagerReadAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:secretsmanager:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:secret:secrets/manager/key/for/user/and/pss-*'
        - PolicyName: KMSDecryptAccess
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - kms:Decrypt
                Resource: !Sub 'arn:aws:kms:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:key/key-id'

  DcpDbManagementLayer:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      LayerName: DCP-Database-Management
      Description: DCP Database Management Layer
      ContentUri: layers/dcp-db-management/
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.9
      RetentionPolicy: Retain

  DcpApiGatewayLogGroup:
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: !Sub '/aws/apigateway/${DcpServerlessApiGtw}'
      RetentionInDays: 14

  DcpBackendReaderFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: DcpBackendReader
      Handler: lambda-function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      CodeUri: src/dcpBackendReader/
      Description: Lambda function for reading from the database
      Tags:
        env: "3"
        serviceGroup: "2"
        owner: "1"
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 15
      Layers:
        - !Ref DcpDbManagementLayer
        - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:acc-id:layer:pymysql:1
      Role: !GetAtt DcpBackendReaderRole.Arn
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-123456789xxxxxxxx
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-0012345678910xxxx
          - subnet-00123456789xxxxxx
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DB_HOST: aurora-host.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
          SM_DNS: https://vpce-12345678910111213x-12345678.secretsmanager.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com
          DB_SM_KEY: secrets/manager/key/for/user/and/pss
          DB_SM_REGION: us-east-1

  DcpBackendWriterFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: DcpBackendWriter
      Handler: lambda-function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.9
      CodeUri: src/dcpBackendWriter/
      Description: Lambda function for writing to the database
      Tags:
        env: "3"
        serviceGroup: "2"
        owner: "1"
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 15
      Layers:
        - !Ref DcpDbManagementLayer
        - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:acc-id:layer:pymysql:1
      Role: !GetAtt DcpBackendWriterRole.Arn
      VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-123456789xxxxxxxx
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-0012345678910xxxx
          - subnet-00123456789xxxxxx
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DB_HOST: aurora-host.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
          SM_DNS: https://vpce-12345678910111213x-12345678.secretsmanager.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com
          DB_SM_KEY: secrets/manager/key/for/user/and/pss
          DB_SM_REGION: us-east-1

  DcpServerlessApiGtw:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: DcpServerlessApiGtw
      StageName: prod
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: '/*'
          HttpMethod: '*'
          LoggingLevel: INFO
          DataTraceEnabled: true
          MetricsEnabled: true
      AccessLogSetting:
        Format: '{ "requestId":"$context.requestId", "ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp", "caller":"$context.identity.caller", "user":"$context.identity.user", "requestTime":"$context.requestTime", "httpMethod":"$context.httpMethod", "resourcePath":"$context.resourcePath", "status":"$context.status", "protocol":"$context.protocol", "responseLength":"$context.responseLength" }'
        DestinationArn: !GetAtt DcpApiGatewayLogGroup.Arn
      DefinitionBody:
        openapi: 3.0.1
        info:
          title: DCP API Gateway
          version: '1.0'
        Policy:
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal:
                Service: apigateway.amazonaws.com
              Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
              Resource:
                - !Sub 'arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:DcpBackendReader'
                - !Sub 'arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:DcpBackendWriter'
              Condition:
                StringEquals:
                  aws:SourceDomain: https://vpce-12345678910111213x-12345678.execute-api.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com
        paths:
          /{database_name}/{table_name}:
            get:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: GET
                type: aws_proxy
                uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${DcpBackendReaderFunction.Arn}/invocations
              responses: {}
            post:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: POST
                type: aws_proxy
                uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${DcpBackendWriterFunction.Arn}/invocations
              responses: {}
            put:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: PUT
                type: aws_proxy
                uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${DcpBackendWriterFunction.Arn}/invocations
              responses: {}
          /{database_name}/{table_name}/{id}:
            get:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: GET
                type: aws_proxy
                uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${DcpBackendReaderFunction.Arn}/invocations
              responses: {}
            delete:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: DELETE
                type: aws_proxy
                uri: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${DcpBackendWriterFunction.Arn}/invocations
              responses: {}

Outputs:
  DcpDbManagementLayerVersion:
    Description: DCP Database Management Layer version ARN
    Value: !Ref DcpDbManagementLayer

  DcpServerlessApiGtwUrl:
    Description: DCP API Gateway URL
    Value: !Sub https://${DcpServerlessApiGtw}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/prod`
```

Tried basically everything mentioned above and nothing, any ideas of why this isn't working?

I'm not using the best practices because I'm still going to update security rules and implement authentication, currently this application doesn't have any sensitive data, I just wanted to deploy it and test if the basics work, but it's not :(

Answer (score 2):

The `httpMethod` inside your `x-amazon-apigateway-integration` object must always be `POST`.

This is the verb for the integration between API Gateway and your data source, not your client.

> The HTTP method used in the integration request. For Lambda function invocations, the value must be POST.

Replace the `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` by `POST`.

Look for `httpMethod` in this documentation page:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html